# Windows - How many memory the program is using makes no sense

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I was wondering how to know how many memory is my program using in real time. I find the PrintMemoryInfo() fuction in win32, and i tried to implement it.

**CODE**

```
 #include <windows.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <psapi.h>

size_t PrintMemoryInfo()
{
  PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS info;
    GetProcessMemoryInfo( GetCurrentProcess( ), &info, sizeof(info) );
    return (size_t)info.WorkingSetSize;
}
inline void printIt(){
  double memory = (double)PrintMemoryInfo() * 0.001;
   printf("%.2f kb\n",memory);
}

int main( void )
{
  printIt();
  char *i =(char*)malloc(100000);
  printIt();
  free(i);
  printIt();
  return 0;
```

`PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS` contains the memory statistics of a process and `GetProcessMemoryInfo` fill it out with the data. I need to know the actual memory size has been using by the program, so i used WorkingSetSize for obtain that.

Microsoft definition:

*WorkingSetSize
    The current working set size, in bytes.*

i passed from bytes to kilobytes and wieh i execute the program i obtain this:

**output**

1. 1974.27 kb
2. 2027.52 kb
3. 2035.71 kb

this program make no sense to me:

1. almost 2 mb of memory for a program doing nothing?.
2. allocated 100 kb of memory but the program is using only 67 kb more.
3. if i freed the memory why this grows up.

Maybe i didn't get what this functions are doing, so can someone explain me what is going on please?

Thank you!

Comment: Try googling the Windows memory model. Modern operating systems are complicated. Luckily memory is cheap and plentiful so most of the time you don't need to care about this stuff.

Comment: WorkingSetSize is not a direct measure of your program's memory usage.   See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684891%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You also have the C Runtime library in the middle managing the heap and requesting memory from the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sum of :

- size of execute file
- stack memory memory that your program occupies the static variables that you use in your program
- heap memory memory that your program takes a dynamic variable
- and size of libraries that is use in program.

Program `alloc` more memory, for construct the code.

Comment: An answer that doesn't contain the words *reserved* and *committed* doesn't address the question.

Comment: So you don't know other words, that similarity or you are limited on reserved and committed? Or u i forget to take words with scientific term? Or u just trolling?